# firebase realtime Database query works 2nd time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase function that calculates the daily sales number. This firebase http function is invoked by an external service every night 10PM. 
What i observed was that it was returning sales as 0. but when i manually invoked the same method one more time then it gave the correct number.

To make sure it is not a problem with the way external service invokes the URL I scheduled it twice at an interval of 5 min. like 10:00 PM and 10:05 PM. And the results are same. That is, the call at 10:00 PM gave me total 0 and the call at 10:05 gave me expected total.

Below is the code that calculates it:

```
exports.daily_sales_report = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    var date = new Date()
    var dateStr = date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getFullYear()
    //query data from firebase
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref('orders')
    //dateStr = "11-9-2018"
    var totalSale = 0  //total sale amount

    ref.orderByChild("order/_date").equalTo(dateStr).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        totalSale = totalSale + snapshot.val().order._orderTotal
    })

    console.log("total final sale:" + totalSale)

    res.status(200).send('email sent')
})
```

why does it work only 2nd time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using promises correctly.  You should only send the response after all the asynchronous work is complete in your function.  Right now, you're performing a query, but not waiting for its results when you send the response.  When you send that response, Cloud Functions will shut down your code, which means any asynchronous work that hasn't completed may never complete.

Also, you sholdn't be using `on()` in Cloud Functions like this.  If you want to query for data a single time, use `once()`, then use the promise returned by `once()` to determine when the query is complete and what its results contain.

Comment: makes sense. but wont child_added be fired once per match?  i just verified that. it fires twice as there are 2 matching records. so if that is the case then how will i know when all of it is finished before returning from the method?

Comment: Use the 'value' event to get the entire results in one shot.  'child_added' doesn't really make sense in Cloud Functions.